# Entity Framework with two databases (with UoW, Repository and Service Layer)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, entity-framework, repository

I have two databases: one for a warehouse, second for the office (The db design is out of the scope of this question). There are MANY cross-database funtions. One of those functions is `IsPurchaseOrderClosed`. I need data from TWO databases to determine this.

I was trying to build a DAL using UnitOfWork and Repository pattern (I always created UoW and Repository classes and interfaces. I knew DbContext already implements both patterns.. but I wanted to abstract EF layer). Anyway.. in this case, I decided to remove both elements and stick with DbContext and Service layer.

Here's my solution:

```
public class WarehouseContext : DbContext
{
    public WarehouseContext()
        : base("name=WarehouseContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<WarehouseContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class OfficeContext : DbContext
{
    public OfficeContext()
        : base("name=OfficeContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<OfficeContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}


public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    public WarehouseContext CreateWarehouseContext()
    {
        return new WarehouseContext();
    }

    public OfficeContext CreateOfficeContext()
    {
        return new OfficeContext();
    }
}



public class PurchaseOrderService
{
    IContextFactory ContextFactory { get; set; }

    public PurchaseOrderService(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        ContextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    //Service method, that interact with two databases:
    public bool IsPurchaseOrderClosed(int poId)
    {
        bool toReturn = false;

        using(var WarehouseContext = ContextFactory.CreateWarehouseContext())
        {
            PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder = WarehouseContext.PurchaseOrders.Find(poId);

            if (!purchaseOrder.IsClosed)
            {
                using(var OfficeContext = ContextFactory.CreateOfficeContext())
                {
                    int invoiceId = purchaseOrder.InvoiceId;

                    Invoice invoice = OfficeContext.Invoices.Find(invoiceId);

                    if (invoice.WasSent)
                    {
                        toReturn = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                toReturn = true;
            }
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this solution good? (By good I mean, does it meet every good-practice advice, SOLID principles etc)
2. In `IsPurchaseOrderClosed` method I get tables using `OfficeContext.Set<Invoice>().Find(invoiceId);` to get particular Invoice object from the database. Isn't it too.. complex/not readable? I was thinking how can I make it more simple? Should I create some kinda generic Service, with all basic/CRUD methods?
3. I have also third question: Currently `ContextFactory` is the part of `.Data` subproject (where my Contexts and Entities resides). Do you think it should be in `.Business` layer, which is the Service Layer (I prefer using Business or Logic words - because many people confuse it with WCF or Windows Service)?

Comment: What I don't understand is why do you `SaveChanges` if you didn't change anything? Have you posted edited code?

Comment: @t3chb0t oh, I cut this code. I close the PO (I also do bunch of other stuff, but it's irrelevant).

Comment: It is not irrelevant. Posting hypthetical/stub code is off-topic. I have to give you a close-vote for that because I'm not going to review an incomlete or edited method. It's too likely that you are going to say "oh, I already have that so it doesn't help". It'd happened too often already.

Comment: @t3chb0t you're right. I just posted the original method, what I have now. I removed all "update" changes because of separation of concerns. The function returns only if PO is closed or not. Is it correct now?

Comment: @t3chb0t Btw. Why would you say it's "hypthetical"? The whole program has over 15 sub-projects and thousands of lines. I can't post everything, because nobody will read it - and help me:/ So I wanted to make it as clear as possible. In any event `IsPurchaseOrderClosed` is 100% real and current

Comment: No, I didn't mean posting everything. You shouldn't :-) but just the relavant parts unchanged. By hypothetical I meant your method that wasn't real since some parts where missing. I'll retract my VTC. Thank you for fixing it.